# "exec format error" when running containers build with Apple M1 Chip (ARM based systems)

Tags: docker, macos, google-cloud-run

Expected behavior: I can run a container I've built using an Apple M1 chip.

Observed behavior:

Assuming you have a Google Cloud Run account and can push Docker images to Google Container Registry. I'm using https://github.com/seenickcode/trivial-go-api for this example.

1. `git clone git@github.com:seenickcode/trivial-go-api.git'
2. `cd trivial-go-api`
3. `docker build -t gcr.io/<YOUR GCR PROJECT ID>/example .`
4. `docker push -t gcr.io/<YOUR GCR PROJECT ID>/example`
5. Go to `console.cloud.google.com`, Google Cloud Run > Create new service > select your pushed Docker image with all default options > Run
6. Error shown:

```
Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. 
Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. 
Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

Logs:

```
2021-04-02 09:35:40.045 EDT
Cloud Run ReplaceService example hello@redactedforso.com {@type: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, authenticationInfo: {…}, authorizationInfo: […], methodName: google.cloud.run.v1.Services.ReplaceService, request: {…}, requestMetadata: {…}, resourceLocation: {…}, resourceName: namespaces/myprojectforso-282419/services/example, response: {…}, servi…
Error
2021-04-02 09:35:49.034 EDT
terminated: Application failed to start: Failed to create init process: failed to load /app/main: exec format error
Warning
2021-04-02 09:35:49.174 EDT
Application exec likely failed
Notice
2021-04-02 09:57:43.102 EDT
Cloud Run ReplaceService example hello@redactedforso.com {@type: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, authenticationInfo: {…}, authorizationInfo: […], methodName: google.cloud.run.v1.Services.ReplaceService, request: {…}, requestMetadata: {…}, resourceLocation: {…}, resourceName: namespaces/myprojectforso-282419/services/example, response: {…}, servi…
Error
2021-04-02 09:57:50.657 EDT
terminated: Application failed to start: Failed to create init process: failed to load /app/main: exec format error
```

System details on where I'm building my image:

- OS: macOS 11.2.3
- Chip: Apple M1
- Docker version: Docker Desktop for macOS v3.3.0 (62345)

Important Notes:

- This all works completely fine for me when I use another architecture, i.e. via Google Container Build or my home Windows (WSL) desktop.
- This also doesn't work with other codebases when built using the Apple M1 Chip, such as another project I have written in Rust as well as Dart. Doesn't seem language related.
- I've been using Google Cloud Run for years, this issue cropped up when using my new laptop with Apple M1 Chip.

Comment: You're building code on an ARM platform and trying to run it on an x86_64 platform. Looking at [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms) it doesn't appear that Google Cloud provides an ARM platform. You're going to need to build your images on a platform that is compatible with your target environment.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You are building an ARM-compatible image which Google Cloud does not support.

I have hit a similar problem pushing my Mac M1 built image to Heroku, which I solved using `buildx` and setting the expected platform

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t myapp .
```

I have written a [Medium](https://medium.com/geekculture/from-apple-silicon-to-heroku-docker-registry-without-swearing-36a2f59b30a3) post to explain the problem and propose 2 solutions.

> Docker is by design multi-platform and can run on different architectures, however, the images must match the platform they will be run on. Which is not our case.

Comment: Makes sense. While the `buildx` approach works for the trivial Go example cite above, when I use it for a medium sized Rust webapp, random libraries fail to compile. I get an exit code 101 and the failure is during compilation of random Rust libraries. Any ideas?

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the errors, I would try the other option (set DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM)

Comment: The DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM method yields the same error unfortunately. Either my system isn't powerful enough or using buildx may be brittle for compiling certain Rust libs. For now, I've reserved a cheap compute optimized AWS spot instance as my build server.

Comment: Good option, I use GitHub action to build my docker images and push them to Heroku. If you are interested one of my GitHub repos has an example.

Comment: Yeah I use a cheap CPU optimized AWS Spot instance with a Buildkite agent on it. Cool thx will take a look.

Comment: This still works perfectly.

Comment: I was getting CrashLoopBackOff from my AKS deployment, that was because I had built my image in my M1 mac, and pushed it to ACR, then when AKS tried to run my image on linux it didn't work

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 20):

As from docker API [version 1.40](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#tag/Image/operation/ImageCreate), you can specify the platform upon which your image needs to be built by using the `--platform` option, without using buildx.

```
docker build --platform=linux/amd64 -t myapp .
```

Comment: I've tried this and it worked. No need to use `buildx`.

Comment: buildx was giving error in AWS, this worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can build x86 compatible image and push to artifact registry with single command:

```
docker buildx build \
--platform linux/amd64 \
--push \
-t us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/your_project/your_registry/myapp .
```

Comment: I tried the both commands:

´docker build --platform linux/amd64´
and
´docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64´

Both didn't work for me.
My specifications are:
MacOS : 13.6
Docker Desktop : 23.0.5

When I tried to run the build image on GCP then I get the 'exec format error'.

Any idea that how can I solve this issue.