# Google cloud run failing with 'Application exec likely failed' error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

We have a process running on multiple cloud runs services for different clients (same code).  One environment is failing and we see the following in the logs.

1. Application exec likely failed
2. terminated: App failed to start
3. POST 503

Application exec likely failed
terminated: Application failed to start: not available
POST 503 746 B 450.8 s python-requests/2.26.0

The only apparent difference between this client and other clients is the number of items processed is larger for this client.  Not sure what this error means.  Is there anyway to get a stack trace or more information on what is causing this?

Comment: I am getting the same error, were you able get the root cause for this. It would be really helpful.

Comment: It appears that your app is taking over 450 seconds to start responding to HTTP requests. That is causing the GFE health check to fail which terminates your container. As always, post your code.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, you have built the image on a Mac. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66920645/exec-format-error-when-running-containers-build-with-apple-m1-chip-arm-based).

In essence, you need to build it like so

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t myapp .
```