# trying to build a docker image from my java app: openjdk:20 linux/arm/v7 - no match for platform in manifest

Tags: java, docker, armv7

I am trying to build an docker image out of my IntelliJ.
It is a Java (openjdk:20) project. I need to have the image as an linux/arm/v7 to run on a raspberry pi 2.
But when I try to build the image a get the following error: ERROR: failed to solve: openjdk:20: no match for platform in manifest

When I run docker buildX ls I see that I should be able to build it:

```
NAME/NODE       DRIVER/ENDPOINT STATUS  BUILDKIT                              PLATFORMS
default         docker                                                        
  default       default         running v0.11.7-0.20230525183624-798ad6b0ce9f linux/arm64, linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/mips64le, linux/mips64, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
desktop-linux * docker                                                        
  desktop-linux desktop-linux   running v0.11.7-0.20230525183624-798ad6b0ce9f linux/arm64, linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/mips64le, linux/mips64, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
```

I am using this command:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm/v7 --tag testarmv7 .
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:20

ENV ENVIRONMENT=prod

LABEL maintainer="XXX"

EXPOSE 8080

ADD backend/target/capstone.jar app.jar

CMD [ "sh", "-c", "java -jar /app.jar" ]
```

I really appreciate any help I can get!

I tried to change the jdk to 17, 11 and 8, but it didnt solve the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build linux/arm64 docker image on linux/amd64 host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70757791/build-linux-arm64-docker-image-on-linux-amd64-host)

Comment: No, thats another problem. I have listed the platform I need ("linux/arm/v7"), but am not able to run the build with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenJDK is deprecated and will not work with your architecture. try with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM arm32v7/eclipse-temurin:17-jammy

ENV ENVIRONMENT=prod

LABEL maintainer="XXX"

EXPOSE 8080

ADD backend/target/capstone.jar app.jar

CMD [ "sh", "-c", "java -jar /app.jar" ]
```

The image arm32v7/eclipse-temurin:17-jammy is a little downgrade from the JDK 20 but will work on your machine. Also the eclipse-temurin offers the JRE only if you needed.

Answer (score 0):

`openjdk:20` is available for `arm64/v8`, not for `arm/v7` which is 32 bit (see [this page](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/openjdk/20/images/sha256-c46cc372084e55b20d5d8bf02859ce96f188c90ed907a8c1fb9c23613b9a4ff3)). It is also a bit old and vulnerable, furthermore the `openjdk` repository on Docker Hub is deprecated (see the [deprecation notice](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk)).

[`arm32v7/eclipse-temurin`](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v7/eclipse-temurin/) has recent images but it supports up to Java 17.  Do you really use some Java 20 feature?  I have not found a pre-built image of Java 20 for `arm/v7`, however consider that Java 17 is the latest LTS so it is not obsolete.

`arm32v7/eclipse-temurin` offers both JDK and JRE images.  It seems that you need just a JRE but you were trying to use a JDK which is bigger; I recommend `arm32v7/eclipse-temurin:17-jre`.