# getting 'no matching manifest for linux/arm/v7 in the manifest list entries' while building docker image on Ubuntu machine

Tags: dockerfile

I'm trying to build docker image for demo app on Ubuntu but I am getting error shown below can anyone please guide me for building image.

### Error

### Sending build context to Docker daemon  19.63MB
Step 1/3 : FROM openjdk:17-alpine
17-alpine: Pulling from library/openjdk
no matching manifest for linux/arm/v7 in the manifest list entries

### Given below content from my docker file

FROM openjdk:17-alpine

ADD demo-app-1.0.jar demo-app-1.0.jar

ENTRYPOINT [ "sh","-c","java -jar /demo-app-1.0.jar" ]

---

I tried changing openjdk:17-alpine to openjdk:8-jdk-alpine and it worked but I just want to know do it openjdk:17-alpine because I am using latest spring version which is not supported by jdk-11

Comment: Hey there.

Error is stating that there is no manifest on Dockerhub for your image. Based on the error you are "refferencing" the linux/arm/v7 architecture for your image, and if you check on Dockerhub for openjdk:17-alpine (https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/openjdk/17-alpine/images/sha256-a996cdcc040704ec6badaf5fecf1e144c096e00231a29188596c784bcf858d05?context=explore), you see the image was only built for linux/amd64 architecture, and not for the linux/arm/v7. If you for instance check openjdk:17-ea-17-slim-buster it also supports linux/arm64/v8 image, which could work for you.

Comment: You could also check: https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/openjdk/tags as an provider for openjdk image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [trying to build a docker image from my java app: openjdk:20 linux/arm/v7 - no match for platform in manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76940132/trying-to-build-a-docker-image-from-my-java-app-openjdk20-linux-arm-v7-no-ma)