# cloud run project gives `Container called exit(1).` and doesn't serve requests

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to setup a basic nodeJS app on cloud run, built with typescript

On checking the cloud logs I see a warning `Container called exit(1).`

Hitting the URL of the project just shows `Cannot GET /`

- Added binding to check that 0.0.0.0 as well as localhost will work
- I've tried using cloud-build to avoid the [problems with building arm on M1 mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66920645/exec-format-error-when-running-containers-build-with-apple-m1-chip-arm-based)
- I also tried building with Docker where my Dockerfile looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh

# image with bin/sh but not bin/bash
FROM node:16-alpine

# needed for node-gyp
RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual .builds-deps build-base python3

# curl
RUN apk add --update curl

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . ./

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure copying both package.json AND package-lock.json (when available).
# Copying this first prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY package*.json ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN npm install --omit=dev

ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0

# for testing local run, not needed on GCP?
EXPOSE 8080

# Run the web service on container startup.
# CMD [ "node", "dist/index.js" ]
# CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
CMD npm run start --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

I've tried various ways to start the service. I have a [justfile](https://github.com/casey/just) with these commands:

```
# building with a build pack, not docker image
build-pack: build-source
  @echo "making build for ${DOCKER_TAG}"
  gcloud builds submit --pack image=${DOCKER_TAG}

gcp-submit:
  @echo "submitting image: ${DOCKER_TAG}"
  gcloud builds submit --tag=${DOCKER_TAG}


# build on an M1 mac for linux/amd64
build-amd: build-source
  docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t ${DOCKER_TAG} .

# deploy from existing docker image
deploy-image:
  @echo "deploy DOCKER_TAG=${DOCKER_TAG} on PORT=${PORT}"
  gcloud run deploy ${GCP_SERVICE_NAME} \
    --image ${DOCKER_IMAGE} \
    --port=${PORT} \
    --allow-unauthenticated \
    --platform managed
```

The image runs fine locally eg:

```
  docker run -p 8080:8080 ${DOCKER_IMAGE}
```

when deploying I don't get any errors

```
just deploy-image                                                                                               
deploy DOCKER_TAG=XXXXX:latest on PORT=8080
gcloud run deploy ${GCP_SERVICE_NAME} --image ${DOCKER_IMAGE} --port=${PORT} --allow-unauthenticated --platform managed
Deploying container to Cloud Run service [XXXX] in project [XXX] region [us-west4]
✓ Deploying... Done.
  ✓ Creating Revision...
  ✓ Routing traffic...
  ✓ Setting IAM Policy...
Done.
Service [XXXX] revision [XXXXX-00004-huc] has been deployed and is serving 100 percent of traffic.
Service URL: https://XXXX.a.run.app
```

(I've XXX'd out the actual URLs)

But then I just get `Cannot GET /` on accessing.

So if this was my own infra maybe the app is running but the PORT mapping is broken?
Or the proxy doesn't know how to find the backend server?

Not really sure where else to look on GCP. =Pulls Hair=

actual GCP error:

```json
{
  "textPayload": "Container called exit(1).",
  "insertId": "633625d6000da4e8178f8c46",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "xxxx",
      "location": "us-west4",
      "configuration_name": "xxx-app",
      "service_name": "xxx-app",
      "revision_name": "xxx-app-00003-nef"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-09-29T23:10:14.894111786Z",
  "severity": "WARNING",
  "labels": {
    "instanceId": "xxx9da465dbd803c39781062c2e1f392e54b524a563aaafa01e7bdb0b769fd62c94898738c506e09f79b1b6"
  },
  "logName": "projects/xxx/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fvarlog%2Fsystem",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-09-29T23:10:14.897307028Z"
}
```

Comment: `Container called exit(1).` would mean it did start a docker container but then violently crashed. Not much knowledge of gcp but If you can for example ssh into the instance and check docker logs you might see why.

Comment: is there a way to inspect the remote container to check it's the right arch? I get 

`docker inspect ${DOCKER_TAG} | grep Architecture
        "Architecture": "amd64",`

it all works locally of course so not sure what else might cause such a crash

Comment: `docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64` defines the arch of the container, it shouldn't be possible to change that afterwards

Comment: I would suggest contacting [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/contact) to further inspect your build and project. It's hard to reproduce the error given that it has a specific error with your application.